# reduce() in function to calculate total of products

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, vuejs2, reduce

```
{
  "orders" : [ null, {
    "comment" : "Bitte, Lassen Sie die Pizza geschnitten.",
    "date" : "2018-06-01 07:22:10",
    "item" : [ {
      "name" : "Tomatensuppe",
      "price" : 3.9,
      "quantity" : 2,
      "size" : ""
    }, {
      "name" : "Estragoncremesuppe",
      "price" : 4.5,
      "quantity" : 1,
      "size" : ""
    } ]
  }, {
    "comment" : "Geben Sie Brot dazu",
    "date" : "2018-03-19 15:22:20",
    "item" : [ {
      "name" : "Minestrone",
      "price" : 3.9,
      "quantity" : 3,
      "size" : ""
    }, {
      "name" : "Tomatensuppe",
      "price" : 3.9,
      "quantity" : 2,
      "size" : ""
    } ]
  } ]
}
```

I would like to calculate a total by orders from this json array.

```
methods:
    grandTotal: function(i) {
      return i.price.reduce((i) => {
        sum + i.price * i.quantity 
          return sum;
      }, 0)
    },
```

In grandTotal function I don't get what's wrong with this approach.

```
<td><ul><li v-for="i in order.item"> {{i.name}} ({{i.size}}) {{i.quantity}} x unit price: {{i.price}} subtotal by item: {{product(i)}}
        <li class="comment-order"><b>Bemerkung: </b>{{order.comment}}</li>
        <li>Total: {{sum}} </li>
        </ul></td>
```

I want to calculate the sum of the row totals, but I don't understand what is wrong with my function.

Comment: it didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are passing entire `item` array to `grandTotal` function. In other words you need `order.item` to be passed in to your `grandTotal` function. Modify your Vue code accordingly.

```js
// Fixed reduce function which takes in an Array and returns sum
var grandTotal = function(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((sum, i) => {
    return sum + (i.price * i.quantity)
  }, 0)
};

var obj = {
  "orders": [null, {
    "comment": "Bitte, Lassen Sie die Pizza geschnitten.",
    "date": "2018-06-01 07:22:10",
    "item": [{
      "name": "Tomatensuppe",
      "price": 3.9,
      "quantity": 2,
      "size": ""
    }, {
      "name": "Estragoncremesuppe",
      "price": 4.5,
      "quantity": 1,
      "size": ""
    }]
  }, {
    "comment": "Geben Sie Brot dazu",
    "date": "2018-03-19 15:22:20",
    "item": [{
      "name": "Minestrone",
      "price": 3.9,
      "quantity": 3,
      "size": ""
    }, {
      "name": "Tomatensuppe",
      "price": 3.9,
      "quantity": 2,
      "size": ""
    }]
  }]
};


var extractedObj = [{
  "name": "Minestrone",
  "price": 3.9,
  "quantity": 3,
  "size": ""
}, {
  "name": "Tomatensuppe",
  "price": 3.9,
  "quantity": 2,
  "size": ""
}]


console.log(grandTotal(extractedObj));
```

Answer (score 5):

```
getTotalQuantity(items) {
    return items.reduce((total, item) => item.quantity + total, 0)
  }
```

items here is an array of objects with qunatity value